# How can I double a time value in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

The task is to double a time from the txt file "time.in" in the format of HH:MM:SS (e.g. 12:22:03) and to output it in the same format (e.g. 24:44:06) in "time.out". I am having trouble skipping the ":" character in the input. Here's my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
FILE *fin = fopen("time.in", "r");
FILE *fout = fopen("time.out", "w");
char c;
double hrs, mins, secs;
double fhrs = 0, fmins = 0, fsecs = 0;

ifstream input;
input.open("time.in");
input>> hrs;
c = fgetc(fin); //what should this be? I can't get it to work properly.
input>> mins;
c = fgetc(fin);
input>> secs;
input.close();

fhrs = hrs * 2;
if (secs < 30) {
    fsecs = secs * 2;
    if (mins < 30)
        fmins = mins * 2;
    else {
        fmins = abs(60 - (mins * 2));
        fhrs++;
    }
} else {
    fsecs = abs(60 - (secs * 2));
    fmins++;
    if (mins < 30)
        fmins += mins * 2;
    else {
        fmins += abs(60 - (mins * 2));
        fhrs++;
    }
}

ofstream output;
output.open("time.out");
output << fhrs <<":"<< fmins <<":"<< fsecs <<endl;
output.close();

return 0;
```

}

Comment: We need more details: what do we do when we have '13:31:31' ? we do '26:62:62' ?

Comment: I already have that part sorted out (it works the way I want with iostream), my only issue is the input from txt.

Comment: `stream::get` perhaps?

Comment: You open 2 times the file with 2 different ways. If you use FILE * fin, you could do `fread('%2d:%2d:%2d', &hour, &min, &sec);`

Comment: What does it even mean to "double a time"? Are you sure you want this?

Comment: Basically we are talking about a time duration, not a time of the day. So in your case 13:31:31 would become 27:03:02. However, that part is not problematic in my code, I am only perplexed by the input not working properly.

Comment: If your problem isn't about some calculation, you should leave the calculation out and give your question a more accurate description and title.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Could you please elaborate? Should I erase lines 14 - 21 and replace them with what you suggested?

Comment: @stefan the task is what I wrote in the description. When I said in the comment that that was not my problem, I meant that I have that part of the problem sorted out, and the reason why it's not working properly is because there is a problem with the input from a file.

Comment: You want an output like `24:44:06` for an input of `12:22:03`? Or should we constrain times to valid times on Earth?

Comment: @JohnAlexandropoulos On stackoverflow, you should not post your task/assignment but rather the specific problem you have. Your problem, as you say, is with input. So please, make a question about input, not about calculation.

Comment: @AndyG As I said, we are talking about a time duration and not a time of the day (a.k.a. what a clock would indicate). Still, that is not what is not working in my code. The multiplication works just fine. What I want to know is how to skip the ":" character.

Comment: @Stefan Perhaps I should make a new and more clear question, then. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Time is not a vector. You cannot "double" it. Only the *differences* of times, i.e. *durations* are vectors.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  However, time and duration can be modeled in the same way.  Both have hours, minutes and seconds.  Maybe this is where some of the confusion is.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Time is an affine space modeled on durations. Time isn't hours and minutes -- it's hours and minutes *since* some reference point (e.g. midnight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ONE of the file-handling routines in C++ or C. Mixing `FILE` and `ifstream` is certain to cause problems.

```
ifstream input;
input.open("time.in");
input>> hrs;
input.get();
...
```

should do the trick. 
If you want to be picky:

```
if (input.get() != ':') ... complain about bad input ...
```